# How do you set up MacVim to compile and run Java?

Tags: vim, java, macvim

I'm reading loads of great things about Vim and MacVim, so I've downloaded it and I've been using it for writing HTML and CSS.

I figure that since I'm new to this whole area, I might as well learn MacVim now rather than waiting until I'm up to speed on coding and then having to slow everything down again to learn it.

The trouble is, when I look for information on setting up MacVim, everything seems to be aimed at professional programmers. I'm loving MacVim's capabilities, but as I'm mostly programming in Java at the moment I'd really like a simple step by step guide to setting up MacVim to use with Java programming. Can someone provide me with a simple, step by step guide to setting up MacVim for Java programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a simple, step-by-step guide (maybe [this old article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/configure-vi-for-java-application-development/5054618) comes close). Maybe [the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Java) proves helpful.

Note that you don't need to find MacVim specific information: all Vim-related configuration is also applicable for MacVim.

Comment: thanks for that dancek, I'll leave the thread open until I've had a chance to review the article properly.